# How do convert Gregorian date to Persian Date in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, date

For example, I want to convert the Gregorian date in Query below to the Persian date

```
select convert(GregorianDate ,persianDate) date
from TOrder
where orderid=?


result:

date:
2021-01-25 ----->convert to ----> 1399/11/06
```

Comment: Complete (and closed) duplicate on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65881951/how-do-i-convert-gregorian-date-into-persian-date-jalali-in-sql)

Answer (score 6):

use this function sql server (MSSQL)

```
select format(GETDATE(),'yyyy/MMMM/dddd','fa')
select format(GETDATE(),'yyyy/MMM/dd','fa')
select format(GETDATE(),'yy/MM/dd','fa')
select format(GETDATE(),'yyyy/MM/dd','fa')
```

[image]

Comment: cam you please post your queries as text. so it is sompler to copy

Comment: Post edited @nbk

Comment: Welcome to the network. Please see [answer] and [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)